# Array of integers boxing

Tags: c#, arrays, boxing

Let's say I have an array of integers and attempt to do a call to `CopyTo()` onto a different array:

```cs
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = new int[3];

a.CopyTo(b, 0); // does b have a completely new set of { 1, 2, 3 }?
```

`CopyTo()` does a shallow copy, but I'm wondering, since `int[]` is a reference type, would this cause the elements within `a` to become boxed and thus no longer be value types?

Comment: `int[] b = new int[3];` is a new reference, so "``b` has a completely new set". `a` is an array of `int`, not `object` that's why no boxing

Comment: Have a look at array specific `Array.Copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've created a *new instance* for array `b`

```
int[] b = new int[3];
```

the answer for your first question

> does b have a completely *new* set of `{ 1, 2, 3 }`?

is *yes*; `b` doesn't share the reference with `a`:

```
// false - a and b are different instances
// even if then can have same items they don't share the same reference
Console.Write(ReferenceEquals(a, b));
```

Since you've created `b` as an array of `int` - `int[]` there will be *no boxing*.; all the items will be *copied by values*. If you want to play with boxing make `b` keep items by reference: `object[] b = new object[3];`; if you want to see *shallow copy* make *both* arrays `objects[]`:

```
// boxed items
object[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

// boxed items
object[] b = new object[3];

// references to boxed integers will be copied 
a.CopyTo(b, 0);

// True
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a[0], b[0]));

// Let's demonstrate that a[0] and b[0] share the same reference:
// We change a[0] and we get b[0] changed as well:

// boxed values don't expose their inner data, let's use Reflection
a[0].GetType()
    .GetField("m_value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .SetValue(a[0], 456);

// 456
Console.WriteLine(b[0]);
```